# Twilio Video Javascript Library doesn't work Firefox -> Chrome

Tags: javascript, webrtc, twilio

I'm using the twilio-video.js 1.1.0 and have cross-browser issues. When using a peer to peer room with TURN enabled, I can see the video:

- From chrome to chrome
- From chrome to firefox
- From firefox to firefox

But I do not see any video from firefox to chrome using a p2p room. Firefox gives the following errors:

```
TypeError: 'get peerIdentity' called on an object that does not implement interface RTCPeerConnection.

ICE failed, add a TURN server and see about:webrtc for more details
```

But I have TURN enabled. If I instead make it a 'group' room instead of peer to peer, everything works fine.

Here is the about:webrtc connection log in Firefox:

```
(registry/INFO) insert 'ice' (registry) succeeded: ice

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref' (registry) succeeded: ice.pref

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type' (registry) succeeded: ice.pref.type

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.srv_rflx' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x64

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.peer_rflx' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x6e

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.host' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x7e

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.relayed' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x05

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.srv_rflx_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x63

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.peer_rflx_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x6d

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.host_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x7d

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.pref.type.relayed_tcp' (UCHAR) succeeded: 0x00

(registry/INFO) insert 'stun' (registry) succeeded: stun

(registry/INFO) insert 'stun.client' (registry) succeeded: stun.client

(registry/INFO) insert 'stun.client.maximum_transmits' (UINT4) succeeded: 7

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.trickle_grace_period' (UINT4) succeeded: 5000

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp' (registry) succeeded: ice.tcp

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp.so_sock_count' (INT4) succeeded: 0

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp.listen_backlog' (INT4) succeeded: 10

(registry/INFO) insert 'ice.tcp.disable' (char) succeeded: \000

(generic/ERR) UDP socket error:Internal error at c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:111 this=0000000013A5EC00

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): couldn't create socket for address IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/UDP

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(generic/ERR) UDP socket error:Internal error at c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:111 this=0000000013A63C00

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): couldn't create socket for address IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/UDP

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(generic/ERR) UDP socket error:Internal error at c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:111 this=0000000013A68C00

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): couldn't create socket for address IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/UDP

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(generic/ERR) UDP socket error:Internal error at c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:111 this=0000000013A81400

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): couldn't create socket for address IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/UDP

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to resolve candidate relay(IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443).

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to resolve candidate relay(IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443).

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to resolve candidate relay(IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443).

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to resolve candidate relay(IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443).

(generic/ERR) Error from TCPSocketChild: type: ConnectionRefusedError, name: Network

(generic/ERR) Error from TCPSocketChild: type: ConnectionRefusedError, name: Network

(generic/ERR) Error from TCPSocketChild: type: ConnectionRefusedError, name: Network

(generic/ERR) Error from TCPSocketChild: type: ConnectionRefusedError, name: Network

(generic/INFO) Write buffer not empty for IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0000000013A5F9F4), not connected

(generic/INFO) Write buffer not empty for IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0000000013A609F4), not connected

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59942/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59942/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(generic/EMERG) Firing write callback (0)

(generic/INFO) Invoking writable_cb on connected (44)

(generic/INFO) Writable_cb IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP (0 (0000000013A5F9F4) pending)

(generic/ERR) UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

(generic/EMERG) Firing write callback (0)

(generic/EMERG) Firing write callback (0)

(generic/EMERG) Firing write callback (0)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59942/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Received response; processing

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59942/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:54.172.60.209:55919/UDP lifetime=3600

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59944/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59944/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(generic/INFO) Write buffer not empty for IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0000000013A659F4), not connected

(generic/EMERG) Firing read callback (1)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59944/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Received response; processing

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59944/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:54.172.60.209:17597/UDP lifetime=3600

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59946/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59946/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(generic/INFO) Write buffer not empty for IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@0000000013A6ADF4), not connected

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) has no stream matching stream 0-1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share) aLevel=0

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59942/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): deallocating

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:59944/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): deallocating

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) has no stream matching stream 0-1500767825144000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share) aLevel=1

(generic/ERR) UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

(generic/ERR) UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 2): 0, waiting: no

(generic/ERR) UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

(generic/ERR) UDP socket error:Internal error at c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/dom/network/UDPSocketParent.cpp:111 this=0000000013580000

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): couldn't create socket for address IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/UDP

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/INFO) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:173 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_create_stun_server_socket skipping UDP STUN server(addr:)

(ice/WARNING) c:/builds/moz2_slave/m-rel-w64-00000000000000000000/build/src/media/mtransport/third_party/nICEr/src/net/nr_socket_multi_tcp.c:617 function nr_socket_multi_tcp_listen failed with error 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to create passive TCP host candidate: 3

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) has no stream matching stream 0-1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share) aLevel=0

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) no streams with non-empty check lists

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) no streams with pre-answer requests

(ice/NOTICE) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) no checks to start

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.1.147:54300/UDP)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.56.1:54301/UDP)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.1.147:54689/TCP) active

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP4:192.168.56.1:51755/TCP) active

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate host(IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:61080/TCP) active

(ice/WARNING) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): failed to resolve candidate relay(IP6:[2001:0:9d38:6ab8:281d:2642:53b2:781f]:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443).

(generic/ERR) Error from TCPSocketChild: type: ConnectionRefusedError, name: Network

(generic/INFO) Write buffer not empty for IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@00000000135819F4), not connected

(generic/INFO) Write buffer not empty for IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP 44 - already armed (@00000000135831F4), not connected

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:54300/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:54300/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(generic/EMERG) Firing write callback (0)

(generic/INFO) Invoking writable_cb on connected (44)

(generic/INFO) Writable_cb IP4:54.172.60.209:443/TCP (0 (00000000135819F4) pending)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:54300/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Received response; processing

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:54300/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:54.172.60.209:10659/UDP lifetime=3600

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate srflx(IP4:192.168.1.147:54300/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:54300/UDP|IP4:54.172.60.209:10659/UDP)

(generic/ERR) UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 1): 0, waiting: no

(generic/EMERG) Firing read callback (1)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

(stun/WARNING) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)::TURN): Error processing response: Retry may be possible, stun error code 401.

(generic/ERR) UpdateBufferedAmount: (tracking 2): 0, waiting: no

(generic/EMERG) Firing read callback (1)

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)::TURN): Received response; processing

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)): Succesfully allocated addr IP4:54.172.60.209:57806/UDP lifetime=3600

(ice/ERR) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) pairing local trickle ICE candidate turn-relay(IP4:192.168.1.147:0/TCP|IP4:54.172.60.209:57806/UDP)

(ice/INFO) ICE(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share)): peer (PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default) Trickle grace period is over; marking every component with only failed pairs as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default)/STREAM(0-1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share) aLevel=1)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1500767829047000 (id=6442450948 url=http://localhost:3000/share):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:54301/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)::TURN): Timed out

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:54301/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): mode 20, nr_turn_client_error_cb

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:54301/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)) failed

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:54301/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): cancelling

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:54301/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): nr_turn_allocated_cb called with state 4

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:54301/UDP|global.turn.twilio.com:3478)): nr_turn_allocated_cb failed

(stun/INFO) STUN-CLIENT(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)::TURN): Timed out

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)): mode 20, nr_turn_client_error_cb

(turn/WARNING) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)) failed

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)): cancelling

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)): nr_turn_allocated_cb called with state 4

(turn/WARNING) ICE-CANDIDATE(relay(IP4:192.168.56.1:0/TCP|global.turn.twilio.com:443)): nr_turn_allocated_cb failed

+++++++ END ++++++++
```

Comment: I found the "solution". When firefox and chrome are connected, if the firefox session simply refreshes (reconnects) the video appears. This seems like an odd bug.

Comment: Glad you have a "solution". Could you send these details to the [Twilio support team](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) who will be able to direct them onto the Video team and hopefully come up with a better solution for all in the future.